# Numpy: efficient way of assigning matrix rows to indexed row in another matrix

Tags: python, numpy

In the following code:

```py
num_centroids = 8

vectors = # ndarray of shape (10000, 128)
centroids = np.random.uniform(-1., 1., (num_centroids   , vectors.shape[1]))

for _ in range(max_iterations):
    distances = sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances(vectors, centroids)

    # can this (the centroid update) be done any cleaner?
    for c in range(num_centroids):
        centroids[c] = np.mean(vectors[np.argmax(distances, axis=1) == c], axis=0)
```

Is there a more efficient or cleaner way (other than the for-loop) to assign each `centroid` (a row in the `centroids` matrix) to the mean calculated from the indexed `vector` matrix, given that the `centroid` index (`c`) and the vector indexing with `argmax` is the same?

Comment: Could you provide a *minimal* working example please? I have no idea what any of those arrays are and only a vague idea of what you are doing with them. An expected output would be nice too.

Comment: Certainly. I have expanded the example. It is a minimal implementation of k-means clustering.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `np.argmin` rather than `argmax`?

Comment: One improvement would be to place the call to argmax/min outside the inner loop.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to do an argsort of the argmax/min array. The first time this will be expensive, but it will get much cheaper with every iteration. If you apply the sort indices to the vectors (rearrange them into their clusters basically), you can replace the loop work np.add.reduceat. I'm pretty sure it won't be any faster though. I'll try it out once I get to my desktop.